# Cone of the map $\tau_{\leq 0} A^{\bullet} \rightarrow A^{\bullet}$.

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

[The article](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/%7Eab233971/pdf/metody_homologiczne_not_190612.pdf)

> **Proposition 3.27.** Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category and let $A^{\bullet} \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} B^{\bullet} \stackrel{g}{\rightarrow} C^{\bullet}$ be a complex in
> $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{A})$ such that $A^{n} \rightarrow B^{n} \rightarrow C^{n}$ is a short exact sequence, for any $n .$ Then there exists $\zeta: C^{\bullet} \rightarrow A^{\bullet}[1]$ such that $A^{\bullet} \rightarrow B^{\bullet} \stackrel{g}{\rightarrow} C^{\bullet} \xrightarrow{\zeta} A^{\bullet}[1]$ is a distinguished triangle in $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$.

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category and $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$ its derived category.
>
> **Proposition 4.5.** Any complex $A^{\bullet} \in \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$ fits into a distinguished triangle
> $$
> \tau_{\leq 0} A^{\bullet} \rightarrow A^{\bullet} \rightarrow \tau_{\geq 1} A^{\bullet} \rightarrow \tau_{\leq 0} A^{\bullet}[1]
> $$
> with
> $$
> H^{i}\left(\tau_{\leq 0} A^{\bullet}\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
> H^{i}(A) & \text { for } i \leq 0 \\
> 0 & \text { for } i \geq 1 .
> \end{array} \quad H^{i}\left(\tau_{\geq 1} A^{\bullet}\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
> H^{i}(A) & \text { for } i \geq 1 \\
> 0 & \text { for } i \leq 0
> \end{array}\right.\right.
> $$
>
> **Proof.** We define $\tau_{\leq 0} A^{\bullet}$ as the bottom row of the diagram of a morphism of complexes
>
> [image]
>
> We define $\tau_{\ge 1} A^{\bullet}$ as the top row of the diagram of a morphism of complexes
>
> [image]
>
> The conditions on cohomology are clearly satisfied.
>
> Next we prove that these two maps fit into a distinguished triangle. **By Proposition 3.27 the cone of the map $\tau_{\leq 0} A^{\bullet} \rightarrow A^{\bullet}$ is a complex $0 \rightarrow A^{0} / \ker d^{0} \rightarrow A^{1} \rightarrow \dots$.** Then the cokernel of $d^{0}$ is isomorphic to the cokernel of $A^{0} / \ker d^{0} \rightarrow A^{1}$, hence the cone is quasi-isomorphic to $\tau_{\geq 1} A^{\bullet}$.

**Question**: Why the cone of the map $\tau_{\leq 0} A^{\bullet} \rightarrow A^{\bullet}$ is $0 \rightarrow A^{0} / \ker d^{0} \rightarrow A^{1} \rightarrow \dots$? I think it is $\dots \to A^{-1}\oplus A^0 \to \ker d^0 \oplus A^1 \to \dots$.

Thank you.

Comment: The two complexes are quasi-isomorphic.